# HQL/MySQL for listing distincts and duplicates

Tags: mysql, performance, grails, hql

I have list of 20.000+ objects. These objects have a fk to a table called title. Two tipps are considered duplicate if they are linked to the same title, and they belong to the same package(tipp_pkg_fk, this is a parameter). 
I need a list of all objects, with the duplicates listed together. For example:

```
tippA.title.name = "One"
tippB.title.name = "Two"
tippC.title.name = "Two"
```

Ideally from the above I will get a list result like this: `[[tippA],[tippB,tippC]]`

I am not sure how to do this, I have made an attempt (first in Mysql so I can test it, then ill change it to HQL):

```
select tipp.tipp_id, 1 as sortOrder
    from (select distinct a.tipp_id as id
            from title_instance_package_platform a, title_instance_package_platform b 
            where a.tipp_pkg_fk= 1 and b.tipp_pkg_fk = 1 and a.tipp_ti_fk = b.tipp_ti_fk) duplicates,
    title_instance_package_platform tipp
where tipp.tipp_id != duplicates.id
union all
select duplicates.id, 2 as sortOrder
    from (select distinct a.tipp_id as id
            from title_instance_package_platform a , title_instance_package_platform b 
            where a.tipp_pkg_fk = 1 and b.tipp_pkg_fk=1 and a.tipp_ti_fk = b.tipp_ti_fk) duplicates
order by sortOrder, id;
```

This executed for 330 seconds, then I got the message `fetching` in MySQL workbench, and computer started dying at that point. So the idea is that first I select all the IDs that are not duplicate, then I select all the IDS that are duplicate, and then I merge them and order them so that they appear together. I am looking for the most efficient way to do this, as I will be executing this query several times during an overnight job.

For my TIPP model, the following are part of the mapping:

```
static mapping = {
     pkg column:'tipp_pkg_fk', index: 'tipp_idx'
     title column:'tipp_ti_fk', index: 'tipp_idx'
}


+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tipp_id                     | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tipp_version                | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tipp_pkg_fk                 | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tipp_plat_fk                | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tipp_ti_fk                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date_created                | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_updated                | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |



+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ti_id           | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ti_version      | bigint(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_created    | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ti_imp_id       | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| last_updated    | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ti_title        | varchar(1024) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ti_key_title    | varchar(1024) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ti_norm_title   | varchar(1024) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sort_title      | varchar(1024) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Update**

After some changes it is working:

```
select tipp.tipp_id as id, 1 as sortOrder
from
    title_instance_package_platform tipp
where tipp.tipp_id not in (select distinct a.tipp_id as id
            from title_instance_package_platform a, title_instance_package_platform b 
            where a.tipp_pkg_fk= 1 and b.tipp_pkg_fk = 1 and a.tipp_ti_fk = b.tipp_ti_fk)
union all
select duplicates.id as id, 2 as sortOrder
    from (select distinct a.tipp_id as id
            from title_instance_package_platform a , title_instance_package_platform b 
            where a.tipp_pkg_fk = 1 and b.tipp_pkg_fk=1 and a.tipp_ti_fk = b.tipp_ti_fk) duplicates
order by sortOrder, id;
```

I still haven't got the duplicates grouped together though, instead everything comes as a list, which means I still need to group them.

Comment: what are your indexes shown via `show create table xxx` for each relevant table. post output in question

Comment: Have you tweaked or altered MySQL's config in any way at this point? 330 seconds for mere 20k rows.. it's just too much.

Comment: To me the SQL seems complex.  If you're simply looking for duplicates, look at using group by name having count(distinct tipp_ID) > 1 to find duplicates  This could be a subquery/inlineview which is joined back to the base set if you need all the tipp_Ids...

Comment: it looks like a funky on clause `on a.tipp_ti_fk = ti_a.ti_id, title_instance_package_platform b ???`   probably a tablescan

Comment: @Drew      pkg column:'tipp_pkg_fk', index: 'tipp_idx'
title column:'tipp_ti_fk', index: 'tipp_idx' these are indexed.

Comment: i would say publish it above and look at on clause

Comment: @Drew you say something is wrong with the join? Normally on HQL it would simply be tipp_a.title = tipp_b.title, and it handles the rest, I thought thats the way to do it in mysql.

Comment: run it thru `explain` is an useful response, but can be confusing cuz I was looking at your tags in profile to see if you are a mysql guy. Mysql Explain manual page [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: No I am not good with mysql when things get very complicated, haven't seen `explain` before, will read it now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do your select from the other side?
select all titles and packages and list all tipps to these, only if a tipp exists (count > 0) and bundle these together to get the array you showed?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could compute both the dups and the non-dups at the same time.  Something like

```
SELECT  ( a.tipp_ti_fk = b.tipp_ti_fk ) AS sortOrder,
        a.tipp_id as id
    from  title_instance_package_platform a ,
          title_instance_package_platform b
    where  a.tipp_pkg_fk = 1
      and  b.tipp_pkg_fk = 1
```

You might need a `DISTINCT`.

This composite index would help:

```
INDEX(tipp_pkg_fk, tipp_ti_fk, tipp_id)
```